# Cannot set decimal value to 0 in the DB (EF Core 7)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have run into a strange issue updating a record in a SQL Server database using C# and EF Core 7.

I have a `decimal` column in the database (type is `decimal (8,2)`).  This column is only updated when the provided value is greater than 0 and will not let me set it to zero, see code below:

```
namespace Accounting.Shared.Dtos.Request.Transaction.Class
{
    public class UpdateDto
    {
        public int TransactionClassId { get; set; } = 0;
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public decimal Percentage { get; set; } = 100;
    }
}
```

The `TransactionClass` model:

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class TransactionClass
    {
        public int TransactionClassId { get; set; } = 0;
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public decimal Percentage { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

And this is the code to update the database:

```
public void UpdateClasses(Accounting.Shared.Dtos.Request.Transaction.Class.UpdateDto transactionClass)
{
    using (accountingContext db = new())
    {
        var updateClass = new TransactionClass { TransactionClassId = transactionClass.TransactionClassId };
        db.TransactionClasses.Attach(updateClass);
        updateClass.Name = transactionClass.Name;
        updateClass.Percentage = 0;   //this only updates in the DB when the value is greater than 0
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return true;                
}
```

There are no error messages and the only constraint set for this column in the database is `NOT NULL`. The default expression for the column has been set to 0 in the database. The other column (`Name`) will update fine even when the `Percentage` column is not updated.

Why can I not set it to zero?

Comment: If it's set in the DB as  _**NOT NULL**_ and default to _**0**_, in the DB call, are you able to check to see if it's 0 first and then omit it from the db save if it is?  Just an idea / something to test.

Comment: The column may already contain a value which I may need to set to 0

Comment: what does TransactionClass look like?  And how is it defined in the db context?

Comment: @ScottMildenberger I have updated the question to include the TRansactionClass Mode.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger I just realised the default value for Percentage in the TransactionClass is "default!" where as in the updateDto is 100.  But why this would prevent updating with zero value when all other values work I do not understand, do you?

Comment: what if you select your model from DBSet first. Update the value there and then save DB context?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue you are encountering is with change tracking behaviour, and I would be cautious about using the approach you are for updating data:

```
var updateClass = new TransactionClass { TransactionClassId = transactionClass.TransactionClassId };
db.TransactionClasses.Attach(updateClass);
updateClass.Name = transactionClass.Name;
updateClass.Percentage = 0;   //this only updates in the DB when the value is greater than 0
```

What this code is doing is attempting to use a new, detached instance of an entity to perform an update. This can work, but it comes with risks because it doesn't take into account whether the data may or may not be stale.

The reason setting .Percentage to 0 "doesn't work" even if the database had a different value recorded is because as far as EF's change tracking (initialized on `Attach()`) the *entity's* value is already 0, *not* what is in the database because the entity initializes to `default!`. So when you attach it, it thinks the current value is 0, not what is in the DB, so setting it explicitly to 0 is ignored by the change tracker.

When updating entities you should be pulling the current entity then updating it:

```
var updateClass = db.TransactionClasses.Single(x => x.TransactionClassId = transactionClass.TransactionClassId);
updateClass.Name = transactionClass.Name;
updateClass.Percentage = 0;
db.SaveChanges();
```

This way the change tracker will know the current state and will apply it to the UPDATE statement if and when the values change.

The technique you use can work for bulk-type operations to attempt to update several records without reading the data first. In these cases the approach would be:

```
var updateClass = new TransactionClass { TransactionClassId = transactionClass.TransactionClassId };
var entry = db.TransactionClasses.Attach(updateClass);
updateClass.Name = transactionClass.Name;
updateClass.Percentage = 0;

entry.Property(e => e.Percentage).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The important thing here is to set the modified state on *just* the values you want to ensure get modified and not the entire attached entity. (Which is what you'll commonly see when developers attach entities to be saved) If you set the entire entity state to Modified then you will be erasing/defaulting every value that you haven't explicitly set in the new detached entity.

Comment: If you do want to use the OP's pattern, you can define nullable backing fields so EF Core can tell the difference between unassigned and default values. (eg https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15182)

Comment: @Steve Py - Using your second method for bulk update is what I would prefer - but I get the error  "'PropertyEntry<TransactionClass, decimal>' does not contain a definition for 'State' and no accessible extension method 'State' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyEntry<TransactionClass, decimal>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)